# Find the maximum value holding key resulting in draw from key/value pair in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm interested to know a way to print the `key` which holds the maximum value. Below are few conditions,

- If we have maximum value out of all keys return that. Example: return 
  `c` and it's value `4` from `{a: 2, b:1, c:4, d:1}`
- If we have two keys have same value and they are the maximum then return both with their values. Example: return `a` and `b` with value `4` from `{ a: 4, b: 4, c:2, d:1 }`
- In above condition the order should be `a` then `c`.
- If all keys have same value then return false or zero or something other than one. Example: `{a: 1, b:1, c:1, d:1}`

Code Block:

```js
let obj = {
  a: 4,
  b: 4,
  c: 2,
  d: 1
};

let maxValueKey = Object.keys(obj).reduce((a, b) => obj[a] > obj[b] ? a : b);

console.log(maxValueKey);
```

Note: would appreciate if you tell me why `-ve` vote ?

Comment: This looks like a homework (hence the dowvotes). Can you explain use what's wrong with your code ? What problem do you have ?

Comment: if two keys have same max value then return both key, else the maximum value holding key

Comment: @Weedoze it's not a homework, It was one of the leetcode challenge i was solving. I ended up looping twice to figure first character which has maxValue so wanted to educate myself if there is any better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` with `Object.keys()` to find the maximum value key and store it in the array.

```js
let maxValueKey = (o) => Object.keys(o).reduce((a, k, i, keys) => {
  if (!i || a.value < o [k]) {
    a.max.length = 0;
    a.max.push(k);
    a.value = o[k];
  } else if (a.value === o[k]) {
    a.max.push(k);
  }
  
  if (a.max.length === keys.length) {
    a.max.length = 0;
    a.value = 'All equal';
  }
  
  return a;
}, {max : [], value: undefined});
console.log(maxValueKey({ a: 4, b: 4, c:2, d:1 }));
console.log(maxValueKey({ a: 1, b:1, c:1, d:1 }));
console.log(maxValueKey({ a: 2, b:1, c:4, d:1 }));
console.log(maxValueKey({ a: 2, b:1 }));
```

Comment: Thank you. Is `a, k , i, keys` corresponds to `accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array` ?

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This will do--

```
let obj = { a: 4, b: 4, c:2, d:1 }   
var maxValueKey = Object.keys(obj).reduce((a, b) => obj[a] > obj[b] ? a : b);
var t=[];
var e=Object.keys(obj);
e.forEach((r)=>{

if(obj[r]==obj[maxValueKey])
t.push(r);
})
alert(t)
```

Comment: thanks for the snippet, Yeah i did pretty much the same and wanted to avoid looping twice to figure out the order and/or max values.